# Get a list of all associated models in CakePHP 3.6

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm intending to create a cell for a CMS menu that populates with links to View & List methods of the controllers for each associated model.

Something to the effect of this:

```
class AssociatedModels extends Cell {

    public function display($model) {
         $this->loadModel($model);
         // here's the bit I don't know how to do
         $associated_models = <some function that retrieves this>
         $this->set(compact('associated_models'));
    }

}
```

It occurs to me that even *if* the function I'm seeking exists, it might require a direct request of that model, ie. 
`$this->MyModel->getAssociated()` or something; if that were the case, is there anyway of doing this dynamically (since the model name is being passed as a string when the cell would be rendered).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is really easy:

```
class AssociatedModels extends Cell {

    public function display($model) {
         $this->loadModel($model);
         $this->set('associated_models', $this->$model->associations()->keys());
    }

}
```